# Scroll to the bottom of a CoordinatorLayout that contains a NestedScrollView and an AppBarLayout

Tags: android, parallax, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, nestedscrollview

Is there a way (programatically or by xml) to scroll to the bottom of the following CoordinatorLayout (see below), so the last element in the NestedScrollView is visible when the screen is displayed?

Attached are the actual screen displayed and the desired screen to display. As you can note comparing both images, when you scroll down, the image has a parallax effect.

I would like that the button (only seen in the second image) at the bottom of the NestedScrollView is visible when the screen loads... just a little automatic scroll is needed!

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Current initial screen displayed:

[image: Current initial screen displayed]

Desired initial screen:

[image: Desired initial screen]

The xml of the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="#000"
                android:paddingEnd="40dp"
                android:paddingStart="40dp"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <TextView
                style="@style/register_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/register_text_1"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/param1"
                style="@style/register_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/param1"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/param2"
                style="@style/register_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/param2"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/param3"
                style="@style/register_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/param3"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/param4"
                style="@style/register_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/param4"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/param5"
                style="@style/register_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/param5"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/param6"
                style="@style/register_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/param6"
                android:textColorHint="#fff"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/accept"
                style="@style/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                android:text="@string/button_accept"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```